# How to access REST APIs in Managed Version

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am using enterprise instance of CDF. I cannot figure out how to call CDF APIs to run a pipeline from Airflow.

Answer (score 3):

The REST APIs are not exposed as of now. But will be available in Q2 2019.

Thanks,
Sree